# Where to put files on a installer?

Tags: debian, directory-structure, packaging

I have a program that I am going to package in a `.deb`. Where should I put files for my program? I have had a look at the structure of things like Epoptes but I cannot figure out where I should put them. The files are `.csv`, bash and python  files, but need to be able to run as not root for some. If you could recommend anywhere as on my testing PC I am using the home directory. Any ideas would help.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Filesystem Hierachy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) which is also the base for [Debian's file system layout](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.1).

`.csv` and shell scripts likely go into `/usr/share/<yourprogramname>` if they come out of the package or `/var/lib/<yourprogramname>` if they're data which changes over time.

Python files are a rather special case, see [Debian's Python Policy](https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Policy) for details.